# Python pseudo service

Tags: python, service

I am writing a python 'sensor'. The sensor spawns two children, one that reads in data and the other processes and outputs the data in db format. I need to run it in the background with the ability to start, stop pretty much as a service/daemon. I've looked at various options: daemonizing, init scripts etc. The problem is I need more than just start, stop, restart and status. I also want to add a 'pause' option'. I am thinking that an init script would be the best option adding start, stop, restart, status, pause cases but how would I implement this the pause functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The communication with daemons is usually done by signals. You can use userdefined signals or SIGSTOP(17) and SIGCONT(19) to pause and continue your daemon.

Comment: Works great using SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 to pause and resume